# Powerbuilder - Retain previously retrieved data

Tags: powerbuilder, datawindow

I am doing multiple retrievals of a composite datawindow and the request was to have them all in one printout. 
I vaguely remember that in the past I was putting something in the RetrieveEne event that retained the data but I cannot recall or locate it in my previous code listings.

Could you help me on this?

Thanx

Answer (score 3):

I found it here
https://pbbraindump.wordpress.com/category/2-datawindows/datawindow-control/

Return 2 in RetrieveStart Event